# How can I accept single space using regexp

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

How can I accept Arabic Letters (I am using `^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF0}]+$` for Arabic letters) **And** Single Spaces ?

Accept :

single space and arabic letters

```
مرحبا بك
```

arabic letters

```
مرحبا
```

**Doesn't accept double spaces**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[ \x{0600}-\x{06FF0}]+$
```

Or do you meen multiple words, seperated by a single space?

```
^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF0}]+( [\x{0600}-\x{06FF0}]+)*$
```

This would then be a word in arabic letters, optionally followed by more words (separated by spaces).

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s?([\x{0600}-\x{06FF0}]+\s)*[\x{0600}-\x{06FF0}]+\s?$
```